# Align problem when I try to center and align items with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I just came across this problem. Everything seems ok, but I don't understand where is the problem. Centering and aligning items at the same time are not good?

Only I wanted to write down 3 div in the column direction. I can not change the structure because I will try something with this structure.

This is how does it look like. https://codepen.io/vortovor/pen/ExXZMzR

```css
  .col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: pink;
}

.col>div {
  background: #ddd;
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="top">
      <div>Hello</div>
      <div>I'm</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="bottom">
      <div>Here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: to vertical align, the flex-container must have a defiend height. If the height is calculated then the height will be calculated to fit the content. To vertical align however, the height of the container must be larger then the contents height!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the height property in your .col add to your code

```
.col{
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

so can see that is working fine:

```css
.col {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}


/* orginal CSS */
.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="top">
      <div>Hello</div>
      <div>I'm</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div>Here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about the div in bottom class? So, "here" still looks like not aligned.

Comment: @A7x because the div (block) is centered. The first block is wider as the text is longer. the 2nd block is smaller because the text is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

the code is fine, what happens is the size of the content of your divs.
if you add a class to all your word divs

```
.a {
     text-align: center;
     border: 1px red solid;
     width: 100px;
   }
```

at the moment you have the width of each word which are different and you alignment is centre, therefore it looks like:

```
                        one
                      onelong
                       oneme
```